# Target Angular 4 CSS to a single page div

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Good afternoon.
Premise: I’m not a web developer and I have little familiarity with all these new names that emerge as mushrooms from one moment to the next. Then I ask you not to give nothing for granted.

My question is very simple: I want to target bootstrap 4 style only on a specific elements (e.g. a div) of my page: the rest of the page hasn't to be involved with this styles.

I notice that a colleague of mine used LESS on an older bootstrap version but I red that it is not support in Bootrastrap 4.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Sergio

Comment: provide class for that div only using `class="bootsrap-class"`

Comment: Hi Manish. Thanks for your comment. Where I have to put Link to the css file?
Thanks a lot,
Sergio

Answer (score 0):

I think to have found the solution but I'd like know if it is the right way.
Here my steps:

I downloaded Bootstrap 4 files using

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6
```

from dos prompt inside a local folder

Then I modified **bootstrap.scss** file placed inside node_modules\bootstrap\scss surrounding all code with a class (e.g. .thisismyclass{...})

I then downloaded Koala from this site
http://koala-app.com/

I added the entire local folder (where the boostrap files are) in the Koala UI.

Automatically it create the .css files near the scss files with the reference to my manually added class.

Now, in my page, I added the refernce to my new css and then I added my main class to the div which must use Bootstrap styles.

It's right?

Thanks,
Sergio